# Error encontrando modulos exportados

Tags: javascript, es6

Tengo un problema y es que usando la libreria `es6-module-loader-dev` me esta dando un error al conseguir las clases que estoy importando. La verdad de manera inicial pense que era la ruta, pero luego de verificarlas, ver si las clases tenian el export y si todo estaba en las rutas indicadas me sigue dando el error.

Mi código es el siguiente:

Clase Vehiculos:

```
export default class vehicle {
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

Clase Carros y drones:

```
import Vehicle from './vehicle';

export class Car extends Vehicle {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}


import {Vehicle} from './vehicle';

export default class Drone extends Vehicle {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Clase Main:

```
import {Car} from './classes/car';
import {Drone} from './classes/drone';
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader-dev.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <script>
        System.import('src/app.js');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Error que me muestra en el browser es:

```
es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1478 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error loading http://localhost:3000/src/classes/car as "./classes/car" from http://localhost:3000/src/app.js     XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/src/classes/car
    at f (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1478)
    at XMLHttpRequest.g.onreadystatechange (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1499)
```

Comment: Creo que ese módulo necesita que especifiquen el sufijo (`.js`) de lo contrario mostrará un 404. Segundo, la importación de `Drone` no te devolverá nada porque la estás exportando por defecto y la importas como independiente (`{}`).

Comment: @Guz Si eso fue un error de mi parte, déjame probar lo que me dices.

Comment: @Guz Gracias eso solvento mi problema, al parecer el webstrom me toda solo nombre sin el .js y no me había fiajdo. Puedes colocarla como respuesta para aceptarla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El módulo `es6-module-loader` requiere que se especifique el sufijo de los módulos (`.js`) de lo contrario mostrará un 404.

```
import {Car} from './classes/car.js';
import {Drone} from './classes/drone.js';
```